# How to ensure that working hours for employee i come right after each other?

Tags: operations-research, constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am very sorry if this question looks confusing. I have tried to solve it but unfortunately I always end up with the same problem.

**Introduction to the problem:**

I have a binary variable $x_{i,h,l}$ which is 1 if employee $i$ works on hour $h$ (basically I have shifts that have a length of one hour) on day $l$ and 0 otherwise.

I need to write up a linear constraint to ensure that if $x_{i,h,l}=1$ and $x_{i,(h+j),l} = 1$ then j = 1 (here j is integer and is between 1 and h-1).

In words I want to ensure that if employee $i$ works on day $l$ and he works for hour $h$ then if he needs to work for more than 1 hour on day l the hours have to come right after i.e. if $x_{i,h,l}=1$ then $x_{i,h+1,l}=1$ but only if he is needed for more hours.

I initially wrote the constraint as

$$x_{i,h,l} \leq x_{i,h+1,l}$$

but the problem is that by writting it up like this I am stating that if $x_{i,h,l}=1$ then he actually has to work for the rest of the day. This is not what I want.

The employees have to be able to work for example for three hours in the middle of the day.

I am very sorry, it is hard to explain. Pleas ask if anything is unclear.

Best Husky

Comment: "Then $j =1$" contradicts "have to be able to work...three hours". You just want contiguous shifts and not $j=1$ (at most 2 hour shifts), right?

Comment: Yes, I just want to ensure that if we want employee $i$ to work for 2 hours on day $l$ then these two hours have to be right after each other. Right now my model is working fine, but the problem is that an employee is assigned for example to work from 06-07 and then again from 15-16. I would like to avoid.@MarkS.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you want to avoid two worked hours with a non-worked hour in between, so for all triples of hours $h<j<k$, we should have $x_{i,h,\ell}-x_{i,j,\ell}+x_{i,k,\ell}\le1$. If any of these quantities equaled $2$, then we'd have working at hour $h$ and hour $k$ but no working at hour $j$ in between.